# "Don't fasten it too tightly" is standard and correct for warning?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say "***Don't fasten it too tightly***" as a warning for a screw on a device? The phrase should be engraved on wood for a study light that makes of almost delicate wood, so users can fasten and open a screw for adjusting, but they should be aware and don't fasten it tightly to avoid breaking or cracking around the screw place. I suggest "***Don't fasten too tightly***". Now is it standard and correct for this purpose?

Comment: "To avoid damage to the wood, do not screw down too tightly" sounds like the sort of thing you might see.

Comment: 'Do not overtighten' is often seen. I have found that quite a lot of men with big hands have trouble feeling when to stop.

Comment: I at least partly meant that telling people not to overtighten may be pointless because people's ideas of sufficient tightness may differ. The average assembler of flat-pack furniture is not a skilled and experienced carpenter.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, on the other hand (har-har), I found it pointless when my bicycle assembly instructions said, "Do not overtighten.  Torque to 35 Nm", since I'm too low-tech to have any way of measuring torque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Do not fasten it too tightly" is not good.  The use of "it" in a sign is typical of a non-native speaker not adapting to the context. Moreover you are missing the specific word "overtighten".

Hence "Do not overtighten" is much better.

Or you can give information, "May crack if overtightened"

You will find that warnings and signs rarely use pronouns.  The message will say "Hot water!" and not "It is hot water".  Or "Turn off after use" instead "Turn it off after use".  This is a form of headlinese. It would not be fluent to write "You may crack it if you overtighten the screw."

Answer (score 1):

For a sign on the item itself, one would probably want a relatively brief text, so either of:

> - Don't fasten it too tightly.
> - Don't fasten too tightly.

would work,. I would incline toward the second, since the location of the sign makes the subject clear and "it" is not needed.

For a separate instruction, the sentence suggested in the comment by  
Kate Bunting:

> To avoid damage to the wood, do not screw down too tightly.

might be better. But any of the three is grammatical and reasonable.